# Base URL is not working properly

Tags: configuration, url, base-url, system-config

Our url is omitting the first '/', like so: `ourdomain.comindex.php` when it should be `ourdomain.com/index.php.`

I've looked everywhere in the config, and haven't found a reason why it should be doing that. The base url is `ourdomain.com/` in the database, but whenever it is used that trailing backslash is omitted and this causes CSS, JavaScript, basically everything to break.

I've noticed in the config panel, when I switch from 'Default Config' to 'Main Website', [this](http://cl.ly/aGsP) is what the base URL is listed as, instead of the base URL in my 'Default Config' [here](http://cl.ly/aGMA/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-18%20at%2012.00.53%20PM.png).

Also, the 'Save Config' button does not seem to be working either, and this whole issue is making me think a re-install is needed.

Comment: What does it say in Configuration-->Web-->Unsecure as Base URL? Could you post a screenshot of that?

Comment: [Here](http://cl.ly/aGMA?_ga=1.255823360.980251700.1425957135)

Comment: Try to to fix it by disabling auto-redirect to base url

Or move your installation into a subfolder and change the BaseURL to it that should also work

Comment: We're hosting using GoDaddy, is there an easy way to do that with them?

Comment: Configuration --> Web --> URL options  there is the disabling, maybe try that first

Comment: Is there any way to edit that in the database or a file? The web interface isn't working because it's sending requests to `domain.comindex.php`.

Comment: Also, I changed from the Default Config in the dropdown to Main Website, and [this](http://cl.ly/aGsP) is what shows. I think this is what's causing the issue, but I can't edit any of the fields.

Comment: Save Config will not work if there are JS errors. I would suggest to edit directly in mysql/phpmyadmin to make sure you have trailing slash in base url

Comment: Yes you should add the slash in the database because now your base URL doesn´t have the trailing slash

Answer (score 2):

It might be because the skin url does not have the trailing / in it. Even when the base url is okey, if the skin url does not have the / you will face this issue.

[image]

Comment: He has all these trailing / . It´s just not visible in the screenshot I assume

Comment: @Thomas which screenshot?

Comment: http://cl.ly/aGMA?_ga=1.255823360.980251700.1425957135

Comment: Yes, all the trailing slashes are there.